# Visual Studio 2010 Project Creating/Opening Problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm encountering a problem in Visual Studio 2010.Problem began after I hibernated my computer,and other day when i opened Visual Studio had problems with finding my existing projects.

After problem occurred I tried to reestablish my projects by using **Open Existing Project** dialog,an error message appears like below

[image: Error Message]

```
c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1347,130): 
The project file could no be loaded.The 'FindDependencies' 
start tag on line 1347 
position 14 does not match the end tag of '_FindDependencies'. 
Line 1347, position 130
```

I tried to disable extensions,delete my current settings but no solution

How can solve this problem ?

Comment: Wrote the error message,stackoverflow's image uploading service seems not working properly !

Comment: Images were ok (until you deleted them), rageshctech maybe saw your question before you uploaded them?

Comment: no, a proxy in my office blocks the image ;) Now I got, no  problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File is probably corrupted. Your start tag is different than it should be (missing underscore).
I have this in my .NET targets file:

```
<_FindDependencies Condition="'$(BuildingProject)' != 'true' and '$(_ResolveReferenceDependencies)' != 'true'">false</_FindDependencies>
```

I recommend reinstalling .NET 4.0, you do not know what else can be wrong.

Comment: Where is this file located exactly ?

Comment: c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets, you posted it btw... And it really is there. It is xml

Comment: Do you think reparing .net framework 4.0 would solve this one ?

Comment: I'm trying this now via web installer.

Comment: I reinstalled (reparing not working) .net framework 4.0 and problem solved :).It seems Microsoft.Common.targets file is corrupted.I also wonder the reason wht it happened ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it was exactly what you pointed out. The underscore was missing in front of the "FindDependencies" tag. After adding underscore back  in place, the project loaded without any errors. I didn't need to re-install .NET 4.0 in my case but as Tomas mentioned there could be other possible problems.